# Analog of HTTP Redirect for SMTP

Tags: email, smtp

In HTTP, you can tell the client who asks for `example.com/foo/` that it should ask for `something.else/instead`.

Is there a way to do it in SMTP? That is, if the client sends a message to `john@example.com`, tell it to send it to `jane@somewhere.else` instead.

I know that I can receive the message and relay it to `jane@somewhere.else`. For many reasons I don't want to relay messages via my server. Instead, I want to tell the client that it should send it to another address.

The reasons include:

- I cannot notify the client of a failure (well, perhaps this can be done).
- My server will be blacklisted if the message was spam.
- The destination server will consult blacklists with my IP and not with the original sender's IP, etc.

My motivation is:

- If this were possible, perhaps it would be a better antispam measure than greylisting.
- My institutional server has no antispam filters, while my personal server uses IP-based blacklists such as Spamcop. After the institutional server has received a message, I can scan the message at the client but it's too late to consult Spamcomp and to inform the sender that the message was filtered out (I consider it *a must* in any filtering). I wish the institutional server could simply redirect people to my personal server, which is a lot better protected and correctly informs the sender of the problem at the SMTP stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sendmail](http://www.sendmail.org) provides [`FEATURE(redirect)`](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/sendmail-4th-edition/9780596510299/ch17s08s45.html) to handle such cases.
It rejects recipient in reply to `RCPT TO:` with

```
551 5.1.1 User has moved; please try <newemail@example.com>
```

Your email server refuses to accept the recipient with hint, it is up to sending host to generate bounce message to the sender.  Spammers may/will get the new email **too**.  I do not know any email servers handling automatically such redirects.

I have not investigated how well it is handled by various email clients and level of details provided in bounce message by various email servers.